# Why am I getting an undefined error with my xml?

Tags: javascript, xml

I was trying to follow the answer from here: [Create XML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340894/create-xml-in-javascript)

I am getting an error in the console "undefined is not a function" for the 2nd line here:

```
var mat = document.createElement("mat");
imgsource = mat.createAttribute("imgsrc");
imgsource.nodeValue = default_matte_source;

total_size = mat.createAttribute("total_size");
total_size.nodeValue = 7.5;

cpu = mat.createAttribute("cpu");
cpu.nodeValue = 12;

cid = mat.createAttribute("cid");
cid.nodeValue = default_matte_cid;
```

Comment: is there really something called `createAttribute` as opposed to `setAttribute`?

Comment: @sabithpocker Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createAttribute()` is a method of `document`, not of individual nodes. You'll want something like:

```
imgsource = document.createAttribute('imgsrc');
imgsource.nodeValue = default_matte_source;
mat.setAttributeNode(imgsource);
```

Comment: How is this different from doing `setAttribute('imgsrc',default_matt_source)`? or both produce same results?

Comment: Essentially the same result; this one (a) returns the attribute element if you wish to manipulate it further and (b) doesn't lower-case the attribute name when working in an HTML context (`setAttribute()` does).