# Generate xml in angularjs using user input data and send it to a web service

Tags: xml, angularjs, http, post, document

I want to create an XML in angularjs from the user input and send it to the web service. Please help me with any code example as i am new to angularjs.

I searched quiet a few sites but i do not see proper guidelines for creating xml in angularjs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `XMLWriter` to create an XML. Then you can pass this XML as a string to your webservice. 
Check this out for [XML Writer](http://flesler.blogspot.in/2008/03/xmlwriter-for-javascript.html).

Here is a tutorial on how to use XMLWriter - 
[Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12504/Writing-XML-using-JavaScript)

You can also use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340894/create-xml-in-javascript) method.