# How to display and generate XML from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to generate an XML file using JS. I am really clueless about where to start.
How can I generate an XML file using js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create XML in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340894/create-xml-in-javascript)

Comment: Please see the FAQ [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: No it wasn't mine. @0stone0

Comment: If the linked post doesn't answer your question, you should include more details, and show us what you've tried!

Comment: Hello, @0stone0 to be very frank I am totally clueless where to start from... I have been using JSON for my projects but haven't work on XML before

Answer (score 0):

xml is just like html, so you can create element and add xml to element then you can parse easy.

Or

Use XMLDocument object see https://www.w3schools.com/XML/dom_document.asp

Comment: Can you show me some example? It would be really helpfull

Comment: see https://www.w3schools.com/XML/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: for more detail click on any function in the first reference and it will open an example for it.